# Bus error severity=corrected, type=Physical Layer | unable to boot / login

Tags: boot, drivers, partitioning, login

After installing a driver for a new PCIe Wifi card, my /vars/logs folder started filling up, where it end up filling the entire disk space and wasn't able to boot Ubuntu ([more info here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1293201/tl-wn881nd-driver-overflowed-my-disk-space-logs-folder-filled-and-crashed-my-u)) and just got a repetitive console error of pcieport Bus Error severity=corrected, type=Physical Layer, and now I can't do anything beyond this black screen to login.

Answer (score 0):

After some reading I found this source from *it's FOSS*: https://itsfoss.com/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected/

1. Turn on your computer and just select in the boot GRUB the *Advanced Options for Ubuntu*
2. Choose the latest Linux Recovery mode
3. Then in the Recovery Menu select the root option to open the console below, click enter to activate it.
4. Enter `ls -s -S /var/log` to view the largest files, for me was `syslog.1` and `kern.log`
5. Delete each file by going first to the directory by `cd /var/logs` and then remove them with the `> {name_of_file}` (ej. `> syslog.1` and `> kern.log`)

You can check you actually deleted them by running the code of 4, then you should reboot by entering `reboot`.

After that you should be able to login to your Ubuntu account and quickly should modify your GRUB file to avoid the saving of this errors. For that I recommend the visiting the link above as it's in more detail. But be aware that is a temporal solution as the error will still be occurring in the background.