# Trying to install a PCI TL-WN881ND wifi card on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, compiling, make

I am trying to install the TL-WN881ND wifi card on Ubuntu 20.04.

The card is not showing inside lspci.
I tried this answer : [Problems installing a TL-WN881ND driver on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150088/problems-installing-a-tl-wn881nd-driver-on-ubuntu-18-04) but it seems the repo no longuer exist.

I downloaded those drivers : https://www.tp-link.com/fr/support/download/tl-wn881nd/

When I try to do make I have the following error :

```
"******************************************"
"NO KSRC,we will use default KSRC"
"******************************************"
  CC [M]  /home/alain/Téléchargements/TL-WN881ND_2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EE_linux_v4.3.15.1_19180_BTCOEX20150615-0041.20160824_OK/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/alain/Téléchargements/TL-WN881ND_2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EE_linux_v4.3.15.1_19180_BTCOEX20150615-0041.20160824_OK/include/osdep_service.h:41,
                 from /home/alain/Téléchargements/TL-WN881ND_2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EE_linux_v4.3.15.1_19180_BTCOEX20150615-0041.20160824_OK/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /home/alain/Téléchargements/TL-WN881ND_2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EE_linux_v4.3.15.1_19180_BTCOEX20150615-0041.20160824_OK/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/alain/Téléchargements/TL-WN881ND_2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EE_linux_v4.3.15.1_19180_BTCOEX20150615-0041.20160824_OK/include/osdep_service_linux.h: In function ‘_init_timer’:
/home/alain/Téléchargements/TL-WN881ND_2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EE_linux_v4.3.15.1_19180_BTCOEX20150615-0041.20160824_OK/include/osdep_service_linux.h:267:8: error: ‘_timer’ {aka ‘struct timer_list’} has no member named ‘data’
  267 |  ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
      |        ^~
/home/alain/Téléchargements/TL-WN881ND_2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EE_linux_v4.3.15.1_19180_BTCOEX20150615-0041.20160824_OK/include/osdep_service_linux.h:268:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  268 |  init_timer(ptimer);
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~
      |  _init_timer
In file included from /home/alain/Téléchargements/TL-WN881ND_2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EE_linux_v4.3.15.1_19180_BTCOEX20150615-0041.20160824_OK/include/drv_types.h:35,
                 from /home/alain/Téléchargements/TL-WN881ND_2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EE_linux_v4.3.15.1_19180_BTCOEX20150615-0041.20160824_OK/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/alain/Téléchargements/TL-WN881ND_2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EE_linux_v4.3.15.1_19180_BTCOEX20150615-0041.20160824_OK/include/wifi.h: At top level:
/home/alain/Téléchargements/TL-WN881ND_2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EE_linux_v4.3.15.1_19180_BTCOEX20150615-0041.20160824_OK/include/wifi.h:994: warning: "IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF" redefined
  994 | #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF 0x40
      | 
In file included from ./include/net/cfg80211.h:21,
                 from /home/alain/Téléchargements/TL-WN881ND_2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EE_linux_v4.3.15.1_19180_BTCOEX20150615-0041.20160824_OK/include/osdep_service_linux.h:81,
                 from /home/alain/Téléchargements/TL-WN881ND_2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EE_linux_v4.3.15.1_19180_BTCOEX20150615-0041.20160824_OK/include/osdep_service.h:41,
                 from /home/alain/Téléchargements/TL-WN881ND_2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EE_linux_v4.3.15.1_19180_BTCOEX20150615-0041.20160824_OK/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /home/alain/Téléchargements/TL-WN881ND_2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EE_linux_v4.3.15.1_19180_BTCOEX20150615-0041.20160824_OK/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
./include/linux/ieee80211.h:1460: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 1460 | #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF  0x100
      | 
In file included from /home/alain/Téléchargements/TL-WN881ND_2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EE_linux_v4.3.15.1_19180_BTCOEX20150615-0041.20160824_OK/include/drv_types.h:95,
                 from /home/alain/Téléchargements/TL-WN881ND_2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EE_linux_v4.3.15.1_19180_BTCOEX20150615-0041.20160824_OK/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/alain/Téléchargements/TL-WN881ND_2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EE_linux_v4.3.15.1_19180_BTCOEX20150615-0041.20160824_OK/include/hal_com.h:413:13: error: ‘file_path’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
  413 | extern char file_path[PATH_LENGTH_MAX];
      |             ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./include/linux/compat.h:17,
                 from ./include/linux/ethtool.h:17,
                 from ./include/linux/netdevice.h:37,
                 from /home/alain/Téléchargements/TL-WN881ND_2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EE_linux_v4.3.15.1_19180_BTCOEX20150615-0041.20160824_OK/include/osdep_service_linux.h:35,
                 from /home/alain/Téléchargements/TL-WN881ND_2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EE_linux_v4.3.15.1_19180_BTCOEX20150615-0041.20160824_OK/include/osdep_service.h:41,
                 from /home/alain/Téléchargements/TL-WN881ND_2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EE_linux_v4.3.15.1_19180_BTCOEX20150615-0041.20160824_OK/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /home/alain/Téléchargements/TL-WN881ND_2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EE_linux_v4.3.15.1_19180_BTCOEX20150615-0041.20160824_OK/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
./include/linux/fs.h:3031:14: note: previous declaration of ‘file_path’ was here
 3031 | extern char *file_path(struct file *, char *, int);
      |              ^~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:270 : /home/alain/Téléchargements/TL-WN881ND_2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EE_linux_v4.3.15.1_19180_BTCOEX20150615-0041.20160824_OK/core/rtw_cmd.o] Erreur 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1762 : /home/alain/Téléchargements/TL-WN881ND_2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EE_linux_v4.3.15.1_19180_BTCOEX20150615-0041.20160824_OK] Erreur 2
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-124-generic »
make: *** [Makefile:1696 : modules] Erreur 2
```

What can I do ?

EDIT: As requested the result of lspci -nnk : https://pastebin.com/ispgua8t

While troubleshooting I opened the computer removed an put back the WN881D card. That's how I found it's model number.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk` Let's see if we can find the wireless. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: We see nothing at all in your paste that is a wireless device. Please check the BIOS/EFI to see if there is a setting to enable/disable wireless.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: No, the diagnostic script do not list my wifi card.

Comment: I checked the bios but It does not seems i can disable a PCI port.

Comment: Since you took it out of its PCI slot to identify it, please be certain it is properly seated. You might also try a different PCI slot. If we cannot get it to appear in `lspci` then no driver will ever work.